# solving the 2-sum algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to write a simple solution to the 2-Sum problem in Javascript. The problem goes: given an array of n integers and a target sum, determine what combinations of two integers will sum to the target value.

I found a few different language agnostic examples using hash tables and tried to come up with a solution in javascript:

```
// Integer set:
arr = [1,4,2,3,0,5];
// Target sum:
arg = 7;

// Generate hash table
hashTable = {};
arr.forEach(function(value, index){ 
  hashTable[value] = index;
});

// hashTable = {
//   0: 4,
//   1: 0,
//   2: 2,
//   3: 3,
//   4: 1,
//   5: 5,
// }


for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (hashTable[arg - arr[i]]) {
      console.log([hashTable[arg - arr[i]], i])
  }
}
```

The solution should be 4,3 and 5,2 but i am getting 3,1 5,2 1,3 and 2,5. I can walk through the for loop with pen and paper and see that I am doing something wrong but I'm pretty sure I am following the langauge agnostic examples I found (for example [here](https://k2code.blogspot.in/2012/01/given-integer-array-and-number-x-find.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number)). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's [a very concise solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4720397/975097) to this problem that would be relatively easy to translate into JavaScript.

Comment: On the second pass of your loop 7-4 is 3. Are you operating on a separate math plane than the rest of the planet? `hashTable[3]` would still be 3.

Comment: @PHPglue sorry I'm really not sure what you are getting at. its an unsorted list and the value 3 happens to be at index 3.

Comment: Dynamical programming bottom to up approach should be the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you output **indices** of summands, while you need its **values**:

```
 console.log([hashTable[arg - arr[i]], i])
```

That's why you get these values:

- 3, 1; which means item at index 3 + item at index 1 = 7
- 5, 2; which means item at index 5 + item at index 2 = 7 etc.

Try changing `i` in output to `arr[i]`, and `hashTable[arg - arr[i]]` to `arr[hashTable[arg - arr[i]]]`, it should work:

```js
// Integer set:
var arr = [1,4,2,3,0,5];
// Target sum:
var arg = 7;

// Generate hash table
var hashTable = {};
arr.forEach(function(value, index){ 
  hashTable[value] = index;
});


for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (hashTable[arg - arr[i]]) {
      console.log([arr[hashTable[arg - arr[i]]], arr[i]]);
  }
}
```

Note that you get symmetric results too because 4 + 3 = 7 and 3 + 4 = 7 as well.
The solution can be optimized by checking while inserting:

```js
var arr = [1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5];
var arg = 7;

var hashtable = {};
arr.forEach(function(x) { 
  hashtable[x] = true;
  if (hashtable[arg - x]) 
    console.log([arg - x, x]); 
})
```

Comment: hmm. yes i see that makes sense. your change fixed it when i = 1 but when i = 3 the output is [1,3] (because the key 4 in hashTable has value 1).

Comment: @SolomonBothwell Oh, yes, you need to wrap the first summand with `arr[]` too, since you need its value too. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks so much. Your shortened answer looks really cool too. Im studying it right now.

Comment: I noticed a bug in both versions. Change the target value to 4 and it will sum the same element (2 in this case). Adding [arg - x] != x to the if statement solves this.

Comment: Actually scratch my last comment. That fix only works if there are no duplicate values in the array. Try running it with arr = [1, 1, 1] and arg = 2

Answer (score 1):

```
function solution(arr, n){
var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (map[arr[i]] !== undefined) {
        console.log(arr[i], n - arr[i]);
    }
    map[n - arr[i]] = i;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```js
function sumPairs(inputArray, expectedSum){
  var a = inputArray.slice(), b = inputArray.slice(), l = a.length, p = [];
  for(var i=0,av; i<l; i++){
    av = a[i];
    for(var n=1,bv; n<l; n++){
      bv = b[n];
      if(av + bv === expectedSum){
        p.push([av, bv]);
      }
    }
  }
  return p;
}
console.log(sumPairs([1,4,2,3,0,5], 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Function working fine for multiple cases.

```
   const twoSum = (numArr, target) => { 
        let numObject = {};
        numArr.forEach((value, index) => numObject[value] = index);
        for (let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
            let diff = target - numArr[i];
            if (numObject.hasOwnProperty(diff) && numObject[diff] !== i) {
                return [i, numObject[diff]];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6];
let target = 9;
let indexs = [];
function sumNew(arr, target) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if ( arr[i] + arr[j]==target) {
               indexs.push(i,j);
               return indexs;
            }

        }
    }
}
let result = sumNew(arr,target);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).